BZip2Compressor unable to decompress XML completely
I have a bz2 file which decompress into an xml. The file length comes close to 270k lines with a size around 20MB.
I have the following code written which tried to decompress bz2 file.
The error I am facing is: The output XML file is incomplete and thus gives error in parsing. The error is XML document structures must start and end within the same entity as the file is not completed so the opening and closing tags does not match.
The output file is close to 270k lines but does not get complete.
I tried to add second argument in BZip2CompressorInputStream as true for concatenation, but still the same result.
private static String defaultUnzipDirPath = "/Users/name/Desktop//UnzipFiles";
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE =  8192 * 32;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    decompress("/Users/name/Desktop/Resources/myFile.xml.bz2", defaultUnzipDirPath);
}

public static void decompress(String bz2File, String unzipFileDirPath){

        File resultDir = new File(unzipFileDirPath);
        if(!resultDir.exists()){
            resultDir.mkdir();
        }
        try{

            BZip2CompressorInputStream bZip2CompressorInputStream = 
                 new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(bz2File),true);

            File file = new File(unzipFileDirPath + "/output.xml");
            file.createNewFile();
            extractData(bZip2CompressorInputStream, file);
        }
        catch (IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
}
    
private static void extractData(BZip2CompressorInputStream bZip2CompressorInputStream, File file) throws IOException{
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while((read = bZip2CompressorInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0){
                bos.write(buffer,0,read);
            }
        }


Use a list instead of the array and then add to the list : List buffer = new List().

I don't think list will help optimize here.

You should add a bos.Flush() after while loop to make sure all the data gets into the stream.

Really it should close bos at the end of the method

Closing the buffer after successful read helped solve the issue.
(As suggested by @Tim Moore in the comments)
